# UI Freezes when speech_recognition runs on button click

Tags: python, tkinter, onclick, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

i created a python file, when click start,micrphone should worked and start talking and if i stoped it should convert the voice to text and add it in the textbox but everytime I click start the application crashed !

```
import tkinter as tk
import speech_recognition as sr


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Voice to Text")
window.geometry("300x300")


def startvoice():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        try:
            audio = r.record(source)
            voice2text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            text_field.focus()
            text_field.delete()
            text_field.insert(0, voice2text)
        except:
            print("error")


button1 = tk.Button(text="Start", width=16, command=startvoice)
button1.grid(column=0, row=0)

text_field = tk.Text(master=window, height=20, width=40)
text_field.grid(column=0, row=1)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: How do you define "crashed"? Does it throw an error, and if so, what's the error?

Comment: @BryanOakley, the windows open when i click Start button its stopped and start loading i need to force quit

Comment: So, it's not so much crashing as it is freezing. How does `r.record(source)` know when it is supposed to stop recording?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `r.record(source)` and below in a separate thread.